# Which is a best practice to start programs automatically in windows, Common startup group or Registry?

Tags: windows, registry, startup

I am writing desktop programs for windows and when I need to put some program to start automatically I always use one of those options:

1 - Put a shortcut to the program in the startup group

2 - Create a value key on  Windows Registry ("SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run")

Which of this options is a best practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how much weight you would apply to the following questions:

As a user, should I be able to deactivate the automatic startup easily, even temporarily?

As a user, should I get the feeling that the developer trusts me to know what I'm doing?

**Clarification:**

If I have a shortcut in the AutoStart folder, I know that I can quickly disable this part by myself and the developer trusts me to do this.

If I don't have this visual clue, I have to actively look for it using more-or-less arcane tools (speaking from experience here).

If the automatic startup is *essential* for the correct function of the program, by all means, put it somewhere I can't get to it. But if it's a nice-to-have thing, like a "quickstarter", then please don't.

Comment: The user always can deactivate this using msconfig, no matter which way I choose.

Comment: How many of your users know about msconfig? And have sufficient privileges to run it?